# getting line-numbers that were changed

Tags: python

Given two text files A,B, what is an easy way to get the line numbers of lines in B not present in A? I see there's difflib, but don't see an interface for retrieving line numbers

Comment: You are only looking for lines in file B that are not in A?  Does the order of the lines matter?

Comment: difflib can give you [unified diffs](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.unified_diff). The [format for these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format) `@@ -l,s +l,s @@` gives you number of lines removed, starting line, number of lines added, starting line.

Comment: Yes, order matters, basically difflib already implements intelligent diff'ing, just not the line numbers part

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.Differ) can give you what you need. Assume:

**a.txt**

```
this 
is 
a 
bunch 
of 
lines
```

**b.txt**

```
this 
is 
a 
different
bunch 
of 
other
lines
```

code like this:

```
import difflib

fileA = open("a.txt", "rt").readlines()
fileB = open("b.txt", "rt").readlines()

d = difflib.Differ()
diffs = d.compare(fileA, fileB)
lineNum = 0

for line in diffs:
   # split off the code
   code = line[:2]
   # if the  line is in both files or just b, increment the line number.
   if code in ("  ", "+ "):
      lineNum += 1
   # if this line is only in b, print the line number and the text on the line
   if code == "+ ":
      print "%d: %s" % (lineNum, line[2:].strip())
```

gives output like:

```
bgporter@varese ~/temp:python diffy.py 
4: different
7: other
```

You'll also want to look at the difflib code `"? "` and see how you want to handle that one.

(also, in real code you'd want to use context managers to make sure the files get closed, etc etc etc)

Comment: Thanks! BTW, this is 1-based, so to get modified line from fileB, it's lineNum-1

Comment: Yeah, that should work correctly as 1-based. It's incremented before it's printed. Right?

Answer (score 0):

A poor man's solution:

```
with open('A.txt') as f:
    linesA = f.readlines()

with open('B.txt') as f:
    linesB = f.readlines()

print [k for k, v in enumerate(linesB) if not v in linesA]
```

Comment: This has quadratic runtime, and does not respect the order of the lines.  Imagine the lines of A are `1`, `2` and `3`, and those of B are `1`, `2`, `3`, `2` -- your code wouldn't produce any output.  Also note that the question asked for lines *not* in A.

Comment: Good catch with asking for lines not in A, corrected that. Yes the runtime is fairly bad, thus poor man's solution. And yes, also a good point that this code does not respect the order of lines.