# comparing files in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I  have  a list of  file paths . To each list element   I am adding  two   strings   A  and  B such that  absolute path  of files  are : file1=A+listelemet  and  file2=B+listelement.  I would   need   to check if the   files  are identical . If identical, ignore. If   not identical print line numbers  and show the  comparison of  those   lines for   the  given line numbers.

I tried    something like this :

```
with open(file1, 'r') as filea:
    with open(file2, 'r') as fileb:
        diff = difflib.unified_diff(filea.readlines(),fileb.readlines(),fromfile=os.path.basename(file1),tofile=os.path.basename(file2))
        for line in diff:
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

but it  does   not give  consolidated  output for each line  number which is  different  in either  or both files

Suppose   I have  a  text file  with :

```
a
s
s
s
d





ssasa
```

and another   with  the following  :

```
a
s
d
ere

ewrwer

werewr
```

I get the   output as:

```
--- asd.txt
+++ asd1.txt
@@ -1,11 +1,8 @@
 a
 s
-s
-s
 d
+ere

+ewrwer

-
-
-
-ssasa+werewr
```

However, I need  output with line  number   printed   and then the difference in that line   for each file

Desired Output in console:

```
Comparing files file1 and file2


    3:  file1:s,file2:d
    4:  file1:s, file2:ere
    5:  file1:d
    6:  file2:ewrwer
    8:  file2:werewr
   11:  file1:ssasa
```

Comment: What is the output instead?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505822/getting-line-numbers-that-were-changed

Comment: Thanks  Rolf , however, i need  lines   which are   either in  file1   only and  only in file 2 only too

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Jaques, I have  added the  desired output in the  question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the output you want, you may prefer using `filecmp` and the following function:

```
import filecmp
from itertools import izip_longest

def file_differences(file1, file2):
    with open(file1, 'r') as f1, open(file2, 'r') as f2:
        for i, lines in enumerate(izip_longest(f1.readlines(), f2.readlines(), fillvalue='')):
            lines = map(lambda s: s.rstrip(), lines)
            if lines[0] != lines[1]:
                out = []
                for f, line in zip((file1, file2), lines):
                    s = f + ': ' + line if line else ''
                    out.append(s)
                sep = ', ' if out[0] and out[1] else ''
                string = out[0] + sep + out[1]
                print('{0}: {1}'.format(i+1, string))


if not filecmp.cmp('file1.txt', 'file2.txt'):
    file_differences('file1.txt', 'file2.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks, I need this for windows  as well

Comment: It gives   me output like this
Comparing files C:\USERS\bbb\DESKTOP\asd.txt and C:\USERS\bbb\DESKTOP\ASD1.TXT
***** C:\USERS\bbb\DESKTOP\asd.txt
    2:  s
    3:  s
    4:  s
    5:  d
    6:  
    7:  
    8:  
    9:  
   10:  
   11:  ssasa
***** C:\USERS\bbb\DESKTOP\ASD1.TXT
    2:  s
    3:  d
    4:  ere
    5:  
    6:  ewrwer
    7:  
    8:  werewr
*****
line  2 is repeated, its not diff

Comment: @user3399495 I updated the answer with to match your desired output. I think `difflib` is not the best tool if you want your output formatted like this.

Comment: Jaques, thanks for the   code, the  11th line would   not  print  11:  file1:ssasa

Comment: @user3399495 That should be fixed now

Comment: Jaques, thanks  this works.   Thanks  much. Just being nitpicky  I have python 2.7  and I use izip_longest instead . Is it   because  of that  that  I get  the two blank lines  in the  output

8: C:\Users\bbb\Desktop\asd1.txt: werewr
9:
10:
11: C:\Users\bbb\Desktop\asd.txt: ssasa

Comment: @user3399495 fixed that too!